# How to configure a local branch to permanently track a differently named remote branch in git

Tags: git, bitbucket

This seems like a really basic operation, but I haven't been able to find a conclusive answer to it.

I often locally create a new branch like this:
`git checkout -b new_feature`

Then later, I create a remote branch through something like bitbucket or gitlab and want to link my local branch to that newly created remote.

I know i can push to that remote via:

`git push origin new_feature:bitbucket_branch_name`

But I find this tedious and wonder if there's a more elegant solution to this, eg. set the remote branch to track once and work with classic `git pull/git push` from then onward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you are looking for is:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/bitbucket_branch_name new_feature
```

Read more about [`git branch --set-upstream-to`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch--ultupstreamgt).

Answer (score -1):

You can set the remote origin by

```
git remote set-url origin bitbucket_url
```

verify by

```
git remote -v
```

Next set branch by

```
git branch -u bitbucket_branch_name/local_branch_name
```

From then on git pull/push works with that as default, i.e. no url needed.