# How do I pull a repository origin master branch ( that I cloned) without using a push?

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitlab

I cloned a repository from GitLab using SSH, using Visual Studio's Clone Or Check Out Code option.

When I open the solution in Visual Studio I want to pull the latest version of the repository.

However the pull option is disabled in The Team Explorer Synchronization.
There is a message

```
The current branch does not track a remote branch.
```

I want to be sure I can't write to a particular repository. (I have read only access anyway)
Thus I am very confused by the [advice here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40547932/visual-studio-git-no-tracked-remote-branch) that I have to set up a push.

I am using VS 16.1.6

I understand that a pull is the same as a fetch followed by a merge.
I can fetch but can't see how to merge using VS either.

Comment: Does the repository actually exist on the remote? As in, has *someone* pushed at least once? Without an initial push, you will be unable to pull (as there are no 'known' differences). However, assuming the repository exists on the remote, you should just be able to hit `Sync` (as is illustrated in the linked answer).

Comment: yes it exists with lots of work in it.

Comment: your branch is not tracking the remote. you need to choose which remote branch to pull.

Comment: How do I do that without pushing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure a local branch to permanently track a differently named remote branch in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079736/how-to-configure-a-local-branch-to-permanently-track-a-differently-named-remote)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+link+branch+to+remote

Comment: In command-line Git, you do not have to have an upstream set to use `git pull`. Who knows what VS wants here, and why?

Answer (score 0):

Something must have gone wrong with my original clone.
I made a new clone and the pull option is available.